# ASP MVC <%: ViewData["Key"] %> and <%=ViewData["Key"] %>

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

We have been using `<%=...%>` as a standard expression scripts. with the advent of ASP MVC we are introducing `<%: ..%>`.

What's the difference between following asp neggets:

```
<%: ViewData["Key"] %> and <%=ViewData["Key"] %>
```

I tried to search on it but didn't find any results..

Regards,
Sumeet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<%:"String" %>
```

is a new syntax in .NET 4.0, which is basically the same as:

```
<%=Html.Encode("String") %>
```

So it's a quick way to encode strings, shown in the view.

The reason you should use it, is to prevent Html-codes being injected in user-input.

For more info check this blog post by Scott Guthrie: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx